# Socket.io with Node Cluster Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am looking to run a Node.js application with the Node cluster module and socket.io. I got it setup using sticky-session and it works but my issue is as following : 
If I connect for example to worker 5.
Another person connects for example to worker 4.
And when I send a message only the other persons on the same worker receive the message, but I want that if I send a message on 1 worker that it gets send to each other worker aswell.

Here my server code.

```
var sticky = require('sticky-session'),
    http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    socketIO = require('socket.io'),
    cluster = require('cluster'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3003;

  var app = express(), io;

  server = http.Server(app);

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
  });

  io = socketIO(server);
  let totalUsers = 0;

  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
      console.log("got request");
      io.emit('chat message', msg+" send by worker "+cluster.worker.id);
    });
  });

if(!sticky.listen(server,port))
{
  server.once('listening', function() {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
  });

  if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('Master server started on port '+port);
  }
}
else {
    console.log('- Child server started on port '+port+' case worker id='+cluster.worker.id);
}
```

Here my client code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val()); Instead  you want to emit to all sockets use this io.socket.emit('chat message',$('#m').val()); OR use socket.broadcast.emit()

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking about.  This does not solve any of the issues with clustered implementations of socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

socket.io, by itself, does not support clustering.  To get proper clustering support so you can emit to all users on all clusters or to any individual user no matter what cluster they are on, you would need to use something like the socket.io redis adapter that records what cluster all users are on in a redis memory database that all clusters can access.

sticky sessions keep a given client on the same cluster, but they don't solve any of the issues related to communicating with sockets that are on a different cluster.  That's what the redis adapter does for you.

Configuring that redis adapter is described in the socket.io doc here: https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/